# SQL Server same string but different results, why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query for a prototype but can't seem to get it to work. I have no idea. The first query was captured using Express Profiler. The second query is just a copy, and paste from the first query. The only difference is that in the second query I copied/pasted the param value directly from the row in the database. Why are these two queries returning different results?

I did change the queries before posting this, so ignore any minor mistakes I may have missed. I did this to remove client specific details.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
                     FROM [Test_Import] 
                     WHERE CONCAT(Name, '' -- '', City, '', '', State, '', '', Zip) = 
                      @Info', N'@Info nvarchar(49)',
                      @Info=N'LLC -- Morganton, NC, 28655'
go

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
                     FROM [Test_Import] 
                     WHERE CONCAT(Name, '' -- '', City, '', '', State, '', '', Zip) = 
                      @Info', N'@Info nvarchar(49)',
                      @Info=N'LLC -- Morganton, NC, 28655'
go
```

Insert values

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Import] ([Name], [City], [State], [Zip])
VALUES ('LLC', 'Morganton', 'NC', '28655')
```

Create table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Import]
(
    [Name] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: posted screenshot to show results, correcting now.

Comment: @user770 see edit

Comment: They _look_ completely identical. So I'm guessing there are hidden nonprintable characters. These can be tricky to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if there is **any hidden characters** beneath the parameter
you can do that by copy and paste this sql into Notepad++ 
**From Notepad++ menu goto view-->show Symbol --> show all characters**

This will help you figure out the difference

Comment: notepad++ isn't showing any characters when I just pasted in the two param values. I pasted both sql queries, and the only thing notepad++ is showing are newlines

Comment: notepad++ didn't show the hidden symbols, U+A0 -- apparently html entity &nbsp; maps to the above symbol. I wonder why.....

Comment: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php is the website i used to find the hidden symbols